# DatetimeProperty to Javascript time

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm a bit confused by how i'm supposed to pass a datetime value from python to javascript.

I have my value stored in the datastore, i retrieve it and then i do something like:

```
<div class="notification" date="{{notification.date}}">
...
</div>
```

and this is the HTML

```
<div class="notification" date="2012-09-21 14:47:54.313000">
...
</div>
```

Then what?

I've found a tons of different suggestions but almost everytime i got errors because the DatetimeProperty, apparently is different from datetime.

Can Javascript parse that date? If so, how? Otherwise, how should i pass that value?

Comment: Recommend that you use a time format that at least includes timezones... or pass times using the UNIX time stamp, which is the number of milliseconds from the [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Date("2012-09-21 14:47:54.313000")
```

Works for me.

Comment: Timezones.  Server and local time could be different.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher that's not a problem. I have to compare 2 dates provided by the server. I keep the comparison client-side because it's only related to the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

If jinja2, perhaps a custom filter first?

```
def datetimeformat(value, format='%H:%M / %d-%m-%Y'):
return value.strftime(format)
```

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters